# In bash, how does one clear the current input?

Tags: bash, input

Suppose in bash you start writing a command like:

```
$ rm -rf /foo/bar/really/long/path/here
```

and then realize you don't want to execute this after all.  Is there a way to clear the input with one or two keystrokes?

What I have been doing lately is prepending echo and enclosing the input in quotes (Ctrl+A, `echo "`, Ctrl+E, `"`) then hitting enter.  Is there a faster way?

Comment: Or, suppose you paste a command, and realize it was the wrong one-liner. Backspace gets really old after about 20 characters!

Comment: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>,  if you want to keep the history refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/9679852/6521116

Answer (score 350, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> to delete everything before the cursor. The deleted command will be stored into a buffer. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd> to paste the deleted command.

   (Optional: Press <kbd>End</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> to jump to the end of the input first.)
2. Alternatively, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to abort what you're typing.

Comment: There is a caveat: Ctrl-C will kill the current prompt, start a new prompt, and set the return code to 1.

Comment: Don't get used to that, use Ctrl-U. Ctrl-C is not that bad in bash, but if you have e.g. a mysql client prompt, Ctrl-C will disconnect from the server which is really annoying.

Comment: Note that on many systems, there is also a terminal 'kill' character which kills the input so far.  Often, that is control-X.  You can check with `stty -a`.  And that will work with any program that is not actively modifying the terminal controls.

Comment: Ctrl-A followed by a Ctrl-K also works. The 'killed' text is stored and you can paste it by using Ctrl-Y. These keystrokes in fact come from the read line library: https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html .. so you can find them in any tool which user interface uses the library (Actually Emacs, bash, etc..). You can customize its behavior by editing the .inputrc file (take a look to the link above for more details).

Answer (score 104):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.  That clears the input line.

Comment: Thanks, I nearly accepted this as the answer.  But I found it clears only the input before the cursor.  In some cases I am in the middle of editing the command, so I would rather remember Ctrl+C instead of Ctrl+U as simply "discard the current input".

Answer (score 31):

Found a short reference at http://www.ice2o.com/bash_quick_ref.html while [searching](http://google.com/search?q=bash+shortcuts).

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> (if not at the end of the line) plus <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> will do it.

Answer (score 28):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> does the trick as well.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> deletes everything from the beginning of the line up to the cursor, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> deletes everything from the cursor to the end of the line. (It is sometimes useful to use only one of them.)

Answer (score 15):

There are two options to do this

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> - this clears the whole line, no matter where the cursor is.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> - this clear the line from the position of the cursor until the beginning.

Comment: "Consider that using C-u (or C-e and then C-u) will store what you 
clear in a buffer so that you can then paste it later using C-y."

Markisisme

a simpler single command is ctrl+_. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056440/undelete-the-deleted-command-in-bash answered by john kug
-- just started stackoverflow dont have enough points to add comment to you answer.

Answer (score 9):

Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> plus <kbd>Backspace</kbd> in bash will clear everything up to the cursor's position.

(In Cygwin, this will clear the input up to the next word. Words are separated by spaces, underscores, ...)

Answer (score 9):

A nice shortcut is pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>#</kbd>. It will prepend a `#` character (thus making the line a comment) and then press enter. If you then decide that you still the need the command, you still have it in your history :)

Comment: In most terminals, this is also the same as Alt+#, which makes it one (chorded) keystroke.

Comment: A simple yet clever solution and I think this is a more user friendly way of cancelling a command. Exactly what I was searching for :)

Answer (score 4):

This is an expansion of [knittl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26609554/175584) that stores the line in the console history by prefixing with a hash. Overcoming drawbacks of the clipboard, such as accidental overwriting or being unable to view the cut line for reference.

### Comment Line & Return New Prompt

Use either key shortcut:

- <kbd>Esc</kbd>,<kbd>#</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd>

A hash character `#` will be prepended to the line, thus turning the whole line into a comment. It will also return a new prompt, as if enter was pressed by the user. e.g.

```
$ #rm -rf /foo/bar/really/long/path/here
$
```

---

### Retrieve Commented Line

To recover the old line from console history use one of the following shortcuts:

- <kbd>Up</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>

*Repeat key shortcut until the desired line appears.*

---

### Quick Hash Prefix Removal

To remove the line's hash `#` prefix there are a few different options available:

*Remove first character and immediately execute command:*

- <kbd>Esc</kbd>,<kbd>1</kbd>,<kbd>Esc</kbd>,<kbd>#</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd>

*Move cursor to start and remove first character, without executing the command:*

- <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Consider that using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>) will store what you clear in a buffer so that you can then paste it later using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Bash in [vi mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-vi-Mode.html) (set it with `set -o vi`), then press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to switch to the normal mode of vi, and type `dd` to delete the current line!

Answer (score 2):

To delete the current line, try:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>

As an alternative you may use:

<kbd>Esc</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>

which requires in ~/.inputrc:

```
"\ed": kill-whole-line
```

see: http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/1690

Comment: If you want just the escape key to clear the whole line add `"\e\e": kill-whole-line` (has to be double press of the esc key though)