# undelete the deleted command in bash

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

If you have written a really long command, say `cd /very/long/path`, and then you do ctrl+c or ctrl+u (if the cursor is at the end), and then you realise that you want the command back, is there any way to get the full line back without re-typing. Is there any trick to change `.bashrc` so that `bash_history` keep track of keys pressed on the shell and not just after the enter is hit.

I have answered a question at [In bash, how does one clear the current input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056394/in-bash-how-does-one-clear-the-current-input) and realised if we have some option like this it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To undo, use either

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>; or
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> (underscore).

See `bind -P` for a full list of keybindings in `bash`.

Comment: Thanks John, I appreciate your corrections. I will be more careful for rest of my posts.