# How do I clear/delete the current line in terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal

If I'm using terminal and typing in a line of text for a command, is there a hotkey or any way to clear/delete that line?

For example, if my current line/command is something really long like:

```
> git log --graph --all --blah..uh oh i want to cancel and clear this line <cursor is here now>
```

Is there a hotkey or command to go from the above to:

```
>
```

?

Usually I will press the <kbd>↓</kbd> key, and if my current line is a brand new one on the history, that will clear it.  But if I'm going through my command history via the <kbd>↑</kbd> key and start editing or using those commands, <kbd>↓</kbd> will only change the prompt to the next newest command in history, so it doesn't work here unless I press <kbd>↓</kbd> multiple times.

Comment: [Shortcuts to Move Faster in Bash Command Line](http://teohm.com/blog/2012/01/04/shortcuts-to-move-faster-in-bash-command-line/)  This page is more illustrative and explains better I think

Comment: FYI [How can I clear the current line of the Windows command prompt?](http://superuser.com/q/397189/116475)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In bash, how does one clear the current input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056394/in-bash-how-does-one-clear-the-current-input)

Comment: You will find a solution to your problem here
[https://askubuntu.com/questions/470966/shortcut-to-clear-command-line-terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470966/shortcut-to-clear-command-line-terminal)

Comment: Someone should put together a quick table of important shortcuts for the top 20 shells (bash, zsh, etc etc etc) and the top 3 OSs (*nix, macOS, and windows). That would be a great resource.

Comment: I do not understand why SO is closing questions as off-topic for software developement when they are clearly related to modern software development, which includes working in a terminal.

Answer (score 2213, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to clear up to the beginning.

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to delete just a word.

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to cancel.

If you want to keep the history, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> to make it a comment.

---

<sub>[Bash Emacs Editing Mode Cheat Sheet](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-emacs-editing-mode-cheat-sheet/)</sub>

Comment: The line deleted by Ctrl-U is recallable with Ctrl-Y, too.

Comment: Wut? So cool thanks keks & kev, ⌃+U is delete all before Cursor, ⌃+K is delete all after Cursor, ⌃+A is to go to the beginning of the line. So technically ⌃+C is the best solution for the Question

Comment: Alt-Shift-# does not work? thought the others do. Alt-Shift-# prints a > character on the terminal

Comment: `U`/`A` and `Y` is more like a cut-paste. Try doing `Ctrl`+`Y` multiple times.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc `ESC` is it's own modifier key in bash. It's used for things like cancelling history navigation (`CTRL`+`r`), or swapping the last two words behind the cursor (`ESC`+`t`).

Comment: +1 for giving not just one option, but tree great tips. Ctrl+C should've been obvious, but I will most likely use Alt+Shift+# in near future and beyond.

Comment: i thought u meant ctrl-c was undo of ctrl-u--- does that exist?

Comment: Any way to do this on a keyboard without a # key? i.e. one you have to press SHIFT + 3 to access #?

Comment: CTRL-U is a bad answer because if you currently have data you already want to paste it is replaced with the text you want delete from the command line.  It does delete the line, but I would rather not have it copy the text.

Comment: If I delete by `Ctrl+U` and then redo it with `Ctrl+Y`, I can do it again and I get double...

Comment: `fn + shift + left/right arrow` will take you to start/end of line

Comment: I seem to remember that this was the key combo we used on the BBC micro to do the same :)

Comment: I am not sure why, but `control` plus `w` clears the whole line for me. I use `tcsh` with ssh.

Comment: This is one of the greatest answers of all SO. `Ctrl + U` also works on Windows!

Comment: By reading https://superuser.com/a/298461 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30991 I found you can put `Escape: kill-whole-line` in your `.inputrc` file, which allows you to use `Esc` to erase the entire line. Unlike `Ctrl+U`, it doesn't matter whether your cursor is at the end of the line, the beginning, or somewhere end the middle. I'm very happy with this! (I would leave an answer, but this question is closed.)

Comment: Another option that doesn't seem to mentioned is `Esc + Backspace` (at least in bash) - deletes all non-word chars + word chars until the next non-word char (will clear line if only non-word chars were used) e.g. given `1,2,3:` and 1st use, `1,2,` remains and after 2nd use `1,` remains and finally all will be cleared.

Answer (score 793):

Just to summarise all the answers:

- Clean up the line: You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to clear up to the beginning.
- Clean up the line: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to wipe the current line in the terminal
- Clean up the line: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to wipe the current line in the terminal
- Cancel the current command/line: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
- Recall the deleted command: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> (then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>)
- Go to beginning of the line: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- Go to end of the line: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
- Remove the forward words for example, if you are middle of the command: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
- Remove characters on the left, until the beginning of the word: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>
- To clear your entire command prompt: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
- Toggle between the start of line and current cursor position: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>XX</kbd>

Comment: note ctrl-k deletes everything between the cursor and the end of the line.

Comment: Remove next word: `Alt + D`

Comment: `Alt` + `D`  does not work thats why I have not include it :(

Comment: `CTRL + L` clears the screen but keeps what has been typed in the current command line.

Comment: CTRL + XX is toggle between ~any~ two last positions of the cursor. Try it, type something, hit combo. You'll be at the start of the line, type something now at the start of the line, hit combo again.  A few times. The toggle isn't with the start of the line.

Comment: Where can I find the full list of shortkey?

Comment: `Ctrl + Alt + >` moves to the end of the input history which is perfect when you want to cancel searching the history.

Comment: Is there a way to change these somehow? I can't find anyone referencing that desire....

Comment: @momomo: These key bindings are controlled by your shell (in cooperation with your terminal emulator, which decides what escape sequences to send for a given keypress). In bash, you can use `bind` or your `~/.inputrc`; in `zsh` or `tcsh`, use `bindkey`. Google "<shell> key bindings" for a bunch of info.

Comment: I don't think I've seen an `XX` key on any keyboard I've ever used.  What is it shorthand for?

Answer (score 259):

I have the complete shortcuts list:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>  Move cursor to start of line
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>  Move cursor to end of line
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>  Move back one character
4. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>   Move back one word
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>  Move forward one character
6. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>   Move forward one word
7. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>  Delete current character
8. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>  Cut the last word
9. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>  Cut everything after the cursor
10. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>  Cut word after the cursor
11. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>  Cut word before the cursor
12. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>  Paste the last deleted command
13. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd>  Undo
14. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>  Cut everything before the cursor
15. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> Toggle between first and current position
16. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>  Clear the terminal
17. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>  Cancel the command
18. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>  Search command in history - type the search term
19. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>  End the search at current history entry
20. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>  Cancel the search and restore original line
21. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>  Next command from the History
22. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>  previous command from the History

Comment: Sorry, But I have provided all the useful shortcut keys, In which 7,8,9,10,11,14,16,17  are the clear/delete short cut keys which we can use as per requirement.

Comment: It should be mentioned that `CTRL` + `L` (16.) preserves the content of the current command line.

Comment: on windows it seems you need to use Ctrl+Shift+A to go to the start of line

Comment: It is missing `Ctrl`+`h`: delete the character before the cursor

Answer (score 45):

Another nice complete list:

```
TERMINAL Shortcuts Lists:

Left            Move back one character
Right           Move forward one character
Ctrl+b          Move back one character
Ctrl+f          Move forward one character

Alt+Left        Move back one word
Alt+Right       Move forward one word
Alt+b           Move back one word
Alt+f           Move forward one word

Cmd+Left        Move cursor to start of line
Cmd+Right       Move cursor to end of line
Ctrl+a          Move cursor to start of line
Ctrl+e          Move cursor to end of line

Ctrl+d          Delete character after cursor
Backspace       Delete character before cursor

Alt+Backspace   Delete word before cursor
Ctrl+w          Delete word before cursor
Alt+w           Delete word before the cursor
Alt+d           Delete word after the cursor

Cmd+Backspace   Delete everything before the cursor
Ctrl+u          Delete everything before the cursor
Ctrl+k          Delete everything after the cursor

Ctrl+l          Clear the terminal

Ctrl+c          Cancel the command
Ctrl+y          Paste the last deleted command
Ctrl+_          Undo

Ctrl+r          Search command in history - type the search term
Ctrl+j          End the search at current history entry and run command
Ctrl+g          Cancel the search and restore original line

Up              previous command from the History
Down            Next command from the History
Ctrl+n          Next command from the History
Ctrl+p          previous command from the History

Ctrl+xx         Toggle between first and current position
```

Answer (score 30):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to wipe the current line in the terminal. You can then recall it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> if you need.

Answer (score 17):

or if your using vi mode, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> followed by <kbd>cc</kbd>

to get back what you just erased, <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then <kbd>p</kbd> :)

Comment: You can enable vi mode by `echo 'set editing-mode vi' >> ~/.inputrc`. Also works in places like python interpreter prompts and some SQL clients

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure if you love it but I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (to go beginning the line) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (to delete the line) I was familiar with these commands from emacs, and figured out them accidently.

Answer (score 14):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> will clear the word to the left.

Answer (score 13):

An alternative to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.

Answer (score 8):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>: **move** up to the beginning of your line to a ring buffer
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>: **move** up to the end of your line to a ring buffer
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>: **move** characters and (multiple) words left from your cursor to a ring buffer
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>: insert last entry from your ring buffer and then you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> to rotate through your ring buffer. Press multiple times to continue to "previous" entry in ring buffer.

Answer (score 7):

To delete the whole line no matter where the cursor is, you can use the `kill-whole-line` command, but it is unbound by default. It can be bound to, for example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> by inserting

```
"\e\C-k": kill-whole-line
```

into your Readline init file (conventionally `~/.inputrc`).

Various remarks:

- To avoid accidentally re-assigning a key sequence that is already in use for something else, you can check all your bindings with `bind -P`. Check for the suggested binding with

  ```bash
  bind -P | grep '\\e\\C-k'
  ```
- The Readline init file name is is taken from the shell variable `INPUTRC`. If it is unset, the default is `~/.inputrc`, or (if that doesn't exist) `/etc/inputrc`. Notice that if you have `~/.inputrc`, `/etc/inputrc` will be ignored. You can use the `$include` directive to reuse the latter:

  ```
  $include /etc/inputrc
  ```
- To reload your Readline init file, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
- Links to relevant manual sections:

  - [Readline Init File](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Readline-Init-File)
  - [Readline killing and yanking commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Commands-For-Killing)
  - [The `bind` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-bind)

Comment: ... or just use `Ctrl`+`c`

Comment: @juanchito Sure, though there are slight differences: `kill-whole-line` saves the command line in the kill-ring, i.e., you can retrieve it later on with C-y ("yank"), and Ctrl-c doesn't do that.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and start typing to search for previous commands in history. Will show full lines.
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> again to cycle.

Answer (score 4):

In order to clean the whole line (2 different ways):

- <kbd>Home</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
- <kbd>End</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Add to the list:

In Emacs mode, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>, followed by <kbd>R</kbd>, will delete the whole line.

I don't know why, just happens to find it. Maybe it's not used for delete line but happens to have the same effect. If someone knows, please tell me, thanks :)

Works in Bash, but won't work in Fish.

Comment: It's the `revert-line` readline command: "Undo all changes made to this line". It's bound, by default, to `M-r` (Meta-R), which can be both Alt-R or Esc R. This means it's not actually deleting the line, only when it was empty to begin with; if you scroll back in your command history and change a command, then issue `revert-line`, it will change back to the command it was originally and not delete the line.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> for deleting the backward words from the end of the line

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> for deleting the forward words from the beginning of the line

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> comments out the current line. It will be available in history if needed.