# On bash command-line, how to delete all letters before cursor?

Tags: bash, command-line

On bash command-line, how to delete all letters before cursor?  I know Ctrl-k deletes all afterward the cursor.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679776/how-do-i-clear-delete-the-current-line-in-terminal).

Comment: [Readline](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html) handles the keyboard shortcuts. See also `man 3 readline`. These apply to very many ineractive command-line tools, not just bash.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

`Ctrl-u` - `Cut everything before the cursor`

---

Other Bash shortcuts,

- Ctrl-a     `Move cursor to beginning of line`
- Ctrl-e     `Move cursor to end of line`
- Ctrl-b     `Move cursor back one word`
- Ctrl-f     `Move cursor forward one word`
- Ctrl-w     `Cut the last word`
- Ctrl-k     `Cut everything after the cursor`
- Ctrl-y     `Paste the last thing to be cut`
- Ctrl-_     `Undo`

And discover more via man page for bash shell: `man bash`

Additional bash command-line shortcut cheat sheet: http://www.bigsmoke.us/readline/shortcuts

See the documentation here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Commands-For-Killing

Obligatory: Learn more about Bash, Linux, and Tech through Julia's comics: https://twitter.com/b0rk/media

[image: Julia on Bash]

Comment: On my system ctrl-b and ctrl-f move one character.

Comment: Where is the "official" documentation about these?   Why you only show fish without showing how to fishing?

Comment: @Problemania I've added a link.  In general, man or info pages are a good place to start, try running the command `man` followed by the name of the unix tool you're using (eg `man bash`).

Comment: I know about `man`.  How can you find info about the above commands in `man bash`?  I tried and couldn't.

Comment: Yeah, for GNU stuff (such as bash), `info` pages can be more complete - that's what the link I posted in the above answer goes to.  To get this from the command line use `info bash` -> Command Line Editing -> Bindable Readline Commands -> Commands for Killing.

Comment: Actually, though the above is in `man bash` for me as well (use `/` to search for text).

Comment: Any idea what's the equivalent to Ctrl+u for zsh?

Comment: In zsh, Alt+w clears all characters before the cursor.

Comment: thank you so much for this info. I didnt know bash had its own man page

Comment: @qazwsx For at least some of this, GNU readline is the relevant software, maintained by the GNU bash maintainer, and in step with it. See https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html . Also `man 3 readline` is full of exotica.

Comment: @VaughnCato, alt-b,alt-f works.

Answer (score 17):

In [**zsh**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell), <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> clears all characters before the cursor.

In contrast to bash this **does NOT cut** them; it just **deletes** them.

This applies to zsh's Emacs mode (which is the default), NOT to Vi mode.

Comment: Actually, I did recently learn that bash does 'cut' when readline (not bash, actually) deletes. On my Linux machine now, in bash, I can cut back a word with control+W and "yank" it back with control-Y. Many vexing and obscure key combos are there, but learning the big hitters is already useful when working in a shell. (If you dare to use vim mode for readline, you can have yank with a different meaning.) My head hurts, but cursor keys are less worn. See https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html

Answer (score 6):

The hotkey `Ctrl+U` should do this for you.