# How to cancel a multiline commit in git bash while typing

Tags: git

I started typing in git bash

```
$ git commit -m 'message
> 
>
```

when I realized I'm not ready to commit yet. How do I cancel this instruction now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clear/delete the current line in terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679776/how-do-i-clear-delete-the-current-line-in-terminal)

Answer (score 3):

You can type Ctrl+C to interrupt a process