# Is there any way of using normal keyboard text selection with a terminal on MacOS?

Tags: macos, terminal

For the last ~10 years I've been used to manipulating text with the <kbd>alt</kbd>/<kbd>⇧</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd> keys. For instance, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> to jump back a word instead, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>     to select that word, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to jump to the end of line, etc.

I understand that terminals have different conventions and historically came first, but I'm used to these shortcuts, they work great and work **everywhere else**. Is there any way of getting the same controls for selecting and manipulating text in the terminal?

I have seen the following questions:

- [How to move the cursor word by word in the OS X Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81272/how-to-move-the-cursor-word-by-word-in-the-os-x-terminal/81299#81299)
- [How do I clear/delete the current line in terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679776/how-do-i-clear-delete-the-current-line-in-terminal)

But they only address moving the cursor, and not selection.

Comment: Do you mean in editor like vi? Or do you mean on the command line? May I also suggest you use iTerm2 and see https://superuser.com/questions/1051668/select-full-word-in-iterm2-using-alt-shift-arrow/1216606#1216606?

Comment: In an ideal world, I would love to have this directly integrated with the command line, so it also works with integrated terminals like the one in VSCode. ITerm2 seems interesting, I'll look into it, thanks.

Comment: Related question at https://superuser.com/questions/444393/how-can-i-select-text-in-the-mac-os-x-terminal-without-a-mouse-for-copy-and-pas

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the macOS version - your default shell may be zsh.

**Shortcuts options are ctrl + a/e to move to beginning/end of line and esc + W/B to move one word backward/forward**

Other popular alternatives are -

a. bash - with the shortcuts listed in the answer by @Hossein Amiri

b. iterm2 - From - https://web.archive.org/web/20230319125947/https://coderwall.com/p/a8uxma/zsh-iterm2-osx-shortcuts

```
Put this in your .zshrc

bindkey "[D" backward-word
bindkey "[C" forward-word
bindkey "^[a" beginning-of-line
bindkey "^[e" end-of-line

And set iterm preferences.
```

Comment: The link has a damaged image, please consider updating the link to the web-archive destination.

Comment: @AndreiSuslov I have replaced the link

Answer (score 2):

**Moving the cursor:**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> Go to the beginning of the line (Home)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>   Go to the End of the line (End)

Hold the Option key option and click on the current line = Jump Backwards

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>   Previous command (Up arrow)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>   Next command (Down arrow)

Hold the Option key option and click on a previous line = Jump upwards

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>   Forward one character

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>   Backward one character

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>   Back (left) one word      or use Option+<kbd>→</kbd>

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>   Forward (right) one word  or use Option+<kbd>←</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>xx</kbd>  Toggle between the start of line and current cursor position


More information : https://ss64.com/osx/syntax-bashkeyboard.html

Comment: Apologies, this question was about text selection - does this answer help with selection? (If instead this answer is more about moving the cursor or going to previous commands, this question links to a previous open question where this answer may fit better.)

Answer (score 2):

You can't, I've beed looking for long time. This is why people use iTerm they have more flexibility with keyboard only.

https://iterm2.com/features.html

**Copy Mode**

Use the keyboard to make and modify selections.

[image]

Comment: How to do this in iTerm? I tried selection but it does the same

Comment: There is a _Natural Text Editing_ Key Mappings Preset in Keys Preferences allowing to change bindings in one click, check this answer for details https://stackoverflow.com/a/56026518/3177863.