# How to quickly delete shell command that is already been typed in console?

Tags: shell

Sometimes, I would type in some shell command in my console before I decide not to execute it. For example, I type something below in my console terminal:

```
sudo rm -r /   # not yet committed! Thank God
```

Well, I realize it is kind of dumb and decide to delete before real execution.

But, I am lazy, I don't want to press the <kbd>delete</kbd> and wait for the backspacing cursor. The truth is this kind of situation is somehow normal to me.

I want to quickly delete the shell command with as less keyboard pressing as possible. Is there any solutions?

Thanks~

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056394/in-bash-how-does-one-clear-the-current-input

Comment: I think you want Control-C.

Comment: I nominated this for reopening with a view to closing it as a duplicate of SO 1056394, as suggested by @kirbyfan64sos.

Answer (score 2):

`Ctrl+u` and `Ctrl+k` are what you are looking for:

```
 Ctrl + k    # Cut the Line after the cursor to the clipboard.
 Ctrl + u    # Cut/delete the Line before the cursor to the clipboard.
```

Other common used shortcuts you might want to have a try:

```
 Ctrl + w    # Cut the Word before the cursor to the clipboard.
 Ctrl + y    # Paste the last thing to be cut (yank)
 Ctrl + a    # Go to the beginning of the line (Home)
 Ctrl + e    # Go to the End of the line (End)
 Alt + b     # Back (left) one word
 Alt + f     # Forward (right) one word
 Ctrl + f    # Forward one character
 Ctrl + b    # Backward one character
 Alt + d     # Delete the Word after the cursor.
 Ctrl + d    # Delete character under the cursor
 Ctrl + h    # Delete character before the cursor (Backspace)
```

And as always, I suggest you to go to [Bash Keyboard Shortcuts](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-keyboard.html) to learn more advanced Bash skills.

Comment: Funny how you managed to list so many keyboard shortcuts yet you omitted `ctrl + c` which is probably what the OP is looking for (as also noted by *kirbyfan64sos*).

Comment: Because the OP is looking for a way to "quickly delete the shell command" not "quickly abort the shell command" , so I believe that `Ctrl + u` and `Ctrl + k` are what the OP want, not `Ctrl + c`

Comment: Fair enough, may still be useful to add it to the list of extra commands though. Nice post by the way, I'll definitely read up on those keyboard shortcuts!

Comment: Note that on many systems, there is also a terminal 'kill' character which kills the input so far.  Often, that is control-X.  You can check with `stty -a`.  And that will work with any program that is not actively modifying the terminal controls.